# Vue JS v-bind image src attribute combining path string with object value not working

Tags: templates, vuejs2, backticks

Clearly I'm missing something simple here. Inside a template I'm simply trying to add a path to an image file name sourced from an object. I've tried a bunch of things, back ticks mustaches, etc. but Vue doesn't like any of them. How do I format this properly?

```
<img class="img-fluid" v-bind:src="assets/img/" {{playerDetail.pic}} alt="">


playerDetail.pic = "player_image.png"
```

Comment: Why not use `computed properties`? for ex: `computed: getImageSource() { return 'assests/img/' + this.playerDetail.pic }`

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something similar `computed: { 
  getImageSource() {
 return require('../assets/img/' + this.playerDetail.pic );
  }
},`

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this

```
img class="img-fluid" v-bind:src="'assets/img/' + playerDetail.pic" alt="">
```

Comment: Thanks @user7814783 this worked but I ran into issues with the webpack-simple template and the app not being able to find the images unless I copied them across to the dist/ folder so I ended up using a computed.

Answer (score 1):

Vue does not support using Mustache syntax on HTML attributes.[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

```
img class="img-fluid" :src="'assets/img/' + playerDetail.pic" alt="">
```

or

you can use the ES6 [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
img class="img-fluid" :src="`assets/img/${playerDetail.pic}`" alt="">
```